# jQuery: submit selector not loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is my HTML and jQuery Code. When I click the button, I don't get any response from the browser.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Test</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <input type="submit" value="button">
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
$(':submit').click(function() {
    // Act on the event
    $('submit').attr('Please wait', 'value')
});
```

The online tutorial I was following.

[image]

Comment: fyi `:submit` has been deprecated http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: wow, so hard to keep updated with all this haha. Thanks @wirey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to `$(this)` inside your callback:

```
$(':submit').click(function() {
    // Act on the event
    $(this).attr('value', 'Please wait')
});
```

Anyway, an `<input>` is a part of a `<form>` element - you should bind the `submit` event of the form itself, and not a single element.

If you just want a button, stick with `<button>`.

Comment: `$('submit').attr('Please wait', 'value')` won't work too. Change it to `$(this).attr('value','Please wait')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
    // Act on the event
    $(this).val('Please wait');
});
```

Should do it.